# Get pull request attached to work item

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to access information about all pull requests that are linked to a particular work item.

The relations on a work item result (e.g. https://.../_apis/wit/workItems/12345?$expand=all) shows links to the pull requests in this form:

`vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/...`

How can I turn that relationship URI into the canonical URL for the pull request using the VSTS REST API? (e.g. `https://.../_apis/git/repositories/.../pullRequests/1234`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To parse information of the [GET Pull Request REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=vsts-rest-4.1) from the response of [GET work item REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1), you **just need to get the pull request id.**

From the response of the GET work item REST API, you can get the pull request URL as:

```
vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4%2Fe89075b8-d7bd-4c3f-b24c-23276d89e8ec%2F106
```

Then get the pull request, you can split the string with `%2F`, then the pull request id is the last part (as the pull request id is `106` in above example).

And to get the pull request detail by the rest api as below:

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/pullrequests/{pullrequestID}?api-version=4.1
```

Comment: A regular expression to get the id in the first group of the response would be: PullRequestId\/.*%2F(\d+)",